# How to display two elements on the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I want to display this slide show and the video inline. I've tried thousand different examples but they couldn't solve my problem. Any helpful suggestion will be an immense help as i'm a beginner to web developing. Thank You!

```js
var myIndex = 0;

carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  myIndex++;

  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }

  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(carousel, 4000);
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow" style="max-width: 600px" style="display: inline" style="float: right">

  <div>
    <img class="mySlides" src="canada.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="canada">
    <img class="mySlides" src="myanmar.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="myanmar">
    <img class="mySlides" src="china.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="china">
    <img class="mySlides" src="italy.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="italy">
  </div>

  <div>
    <video width="400" controls style="float: right" style="display: inline" poster="http://via.placeholder.com/320x280?text=video">
  <source src="Intro.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
 </video>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This should be all you need to get you started: `.slideshow > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}`

Comment: Could you please explain me that what is done by this 'vertical-align: top'? @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: It's just a way to have both `div`s vertically align to the top of the containing element so that they sit neatly in-line with each other. I suppose the best way to demonstrate it would be to declare a `width` for both `div`s and apply a `border` value (e.g: `.slideshow > div { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 50%, border: 1px solid black;}`), then toggle the `vertical-align` rule on and off to see the change. Give it a try.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yeah it was a good solution. Now it's neat and clear. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Any time you want to put two elements on the same row, give their parent `display: flex`.

By default, the children of a flex container line up side by side. You can then use flex properties to control their size and positioning.

Alternatively, you can switch the `display` value of child elements to `inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: So can I add << style = "display: flex" >> inline with the div tags? Is that what you meant? :( @Michael_B

Comment: If you want the div children to align side-by-side, give their parent `display: flex`. This should be all you need: `<div class="slideshow" style="max-width: 600px; display: flex">`.

Comment: Thank You so much! I could solve the problem up to some extent with the help of your suggestion :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can use flexboxes to put two elements side-by-side. CSS-tricks has a very [thorough guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the topic, so I won't bre you with the details.

In your particular case, use something like:

```
.slideshow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  // no float and similar here
}

.slideshow > div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

You may need to prefix the `flex` and `justify-content` for better cross-browser support, and you may need to add `flex: 1` for IE 10 support.

You could also clean the code up a little. You don't want to use whitespace around the `=` sign in the attributes, and you don't need to specify the `style` attribute multiple times. One is enough, with semicolon-separated rules.

Comment: Thank You so damn a lot @hayavuk. Your suggestion was a pretty good explanation and it  solved my problem up to some extent. Now it's inline as I wanted with a space in between. But I want to bring that video to fit in the right side in the same line. It seems like changing the size won't solve the issue. Any idea to solve that issue also? :/

Comment: I'm not sure about the video, but that's a completely unrelated topic. I think I've seen something about it here on SO, so do some searching. "Fit HTML5 video within container" or something along those lines.